# QTextEdit not Setting Text

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm sure there most be a simple explanation for my problem but I just don't see it.
I'm trying to read a text file into a QTextEdit but apparently i'm unable to change the QTextEdit text in this method and I can't see why.

```
Document::Document(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    this->layout->setSpacing(2);
    this->layout->setMargin(0);
    this->setLayout(layout);
    this->textArea = new QTextEdit(this);
    this->textArea->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
    this->textArea->setAcceptDrops(true);
    this->textArea->setAcceptRichText(true);
    this->textArea->setUndoRedoEnabled(true);
    this->textArea->setFont(QFont("Mono" , 11));
    this->layout->addWidget(textArea);
    this->textArea->show();
    this->textArea->setFocus();
    this->textArea->setText("Prueba de texto1");
}

void Document::open(QString archivo)
{
    std::cout << "Opening..................." << std::endl;
    this->textArea->setPlainText("Prueba de texto2");
    QFile file(archivo);
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    //this->textArea->append(stream.readAll());
    this->textArea->setText(stream.readAll());
    std::cout << "Opened" << std::endl;

}
```

The first time I use SetText during the constructor it works fine but when I call it from open it doesn't work. Help please

Comment: Are you sure the file is opened correctly? Do you see `"Prueba de texto2"` in your textedit? If you do then something is wrong with your filepath or file. Instead of `setText()` try `setPlainText()` does that work?

Comment: I'm getting the filepath via QFileDialog so it should be ok. The textEdit doesn't show "Prueba De Texto2", it stays in "Prueba de Texto1"

Comment: Are you sure that `Document::open()` is called?

Comment: Yes, te terminal displays the "Opening............" and then the "Opened" Strings

Comment: Try to clear 'textarea->clear()' before writing in it.

Comment: It clears the text but doesn't  set the contents of the file

Comment: Ok I tried to cout the contents of the file and it dosn't print anything, I guess it isn't reading the file

Comment: I got it, I had to open the file before trying to read from it. I just assumed Qt would do thar in the constructor of the QFile, but it doesn't.

Comment: what happens between the constructor and open()

Comment: @Topo if you find an answer to your own question, put it as an answer and accept it...this takes the question off of the "unanswered" list.  It's not a bad thing to answer your own question--you are encouraged to do this.

Comment: Thanks @HostileFork I tried that yestarday but since I have less than 100 rer, I had to wait some time to do it. Anyway dschulz already find the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `open()` on the `QFile` object

```
    QFile file(archivo); 
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly){
         QTextStream stream(&file);
         ...
    } else {
        /// Oops, no pude abrir el archivo para leer :(
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this->textArea->setPlainText(QString(stream.readAll());
```

or better yet replace the whole stream thing with

```
QFile *file = new QFile(archivo);
this->textArea->setPlainText(QString(file->readAll()));
```